# Email a different range image to each of the recipients

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

My code sends:

- different attachments to different recipients
- the same range of the Excel sheet (ex: F27:J28) as an image in the email body to all the recipients
- personalized message

I would like to send different ranges to different recipients (like the attachments).

The ranges have the same size and one is below the other. By order, first email first range.

For example:

- Email 1: Range F27:J28
- Email 2: Range F29:J30
- Email 3: Range F31:J32
- etc...

```vb
Sub Send_Files()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MakeJPG As String
    Dim PictureRange As Range
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")
        
        MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet1", "F31: J37")
        
        If MakeJPG = "" Then
            MsgBox "Something go wrong, we can't create the mail"
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = True
                .ScreenUpdating = True
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        On Error Resume Next

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .Display
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = Range("B11") & Range("H13") & " - " & cell.Offset(0, 2)
                .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 0
                .HTMLBody = "Bonjour " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & Range("B15") & " " & Range("C15") & " " & Range("D15") & "<p>" & Range("B16") & "<p>" & "<\p>" & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=550 height=150></html>" & "<p>" & "<\p>" & Range("B17") & .HTMLBody
                
                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub


Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
    Dim PictureRange As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
        Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
        
        If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        PictureRange.CopyPicture
        With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
            .Activate
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
        End With
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    End With
    
    CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
    Set PictureRange = Nothing
End Function


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: What links a particular range to an individual email address ?

Comment: The ranges have the same size and one is below the other. By order, first email first range.

Comment: What is the first one, is it really "A1 B3" ?

Comment: No, I'm not sure I can send a photo here. I can move them wherever. My first range is F27:J28, they are mini tables that I would like to include in the email body. My 2nd range is F29:J30, then F31:J32 ...

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial image range and then offset it after each email sent .

```
Set rngImage = sh.Range("F27:J28")
Set rngImage = rngImage.Offset(rngImage.Rows.Count)
```

With the constant `TEST = True` this code should run without sending emails. If correct set `TEST = False`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Files()

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, cellA, rngA As Range
    Dim jpgFilename As String, filename As String, html As String
    Dim rngImage As Range, sImage As String, n As Long
    
    Const TEST = True ' set to False to use Outlook
    Const IMG_NAME = "Image_"
    Const IMG_RANGE = "F27:J28" ' first email
    
    If Not TEST Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngImage = ws.Range(IMG_RANGE) ' first image
    
    ' scan column B for valid email addresses
    For Each cell In ws.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rngA = cell.Offset(,1).Resize(, 24) ' C:Z attachments
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngA) = 0 Then
            ' no attachments - do nothing
        ElseIf cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        
            sImage = IMG_NAME & rngImage.Row & ".jpg" ' unique image name for each email
            jpgFilename = CopyRangeToJPG(rngImage, sImage)
            
            ' email body
            html = "Bonjour " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "," & "<br/><br/>" _
                    & ws.Range("B15") & " " & ws.Range("C15") & " " & ws.Range("D15") & _
                    "<p>" & ws.Range("B16") & "</p><br/>" & _
                    "<img src=""cid:" & sImage & """ width=550 height=150>" & _
                    "<br/>" & ws.Range("B17")
            If TEST Then
                MsgBox "Image: " & jpgFilename & vbLf & html, vbInformation, "To: " & cell.Value
                'Debug.Print html
            Else
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                With OutMail
                    .Display
                    .To = cell.Value
                    .Subject = Range("B11") & Range("H13") & " - " & cell.Offset(0, 2)
                    .Attachments.Add jpgFilename, 1, 0
                    .HTMLBody = html & .HTMLBody
                    
                    ' add attachments
                    For Each cellA In rngA.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        filename = Trim(cellA.Value)
                        If filename <> "" Then
                            If Dir(filename) <> "" Then ' check file exists
                                .Attachments.Add filename
                            Else
                                MsgBox "Could not attach : " & filename, vbExclamation, cell.Value
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End With
                Set OutMail = Nothing
            End If
            
            ' next image
            Set rngImage = rngImage.Offset(rngImage.Rows.Count)
            n = n + 1
            
        End If
    Next
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox n & " emails sent", vbInformation
   
End Sub

Function CopyRangeToJPG(rngImage As Range, filename As String) As String
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, folder As String
    Set ws = rngImage.Parent ' sheet
    
    ' check range
    If rngImage Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
        CopyRangeToJPG = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' create image file
    folder = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator
    rngImage.CopyPicture
    With ws.ChartObjects.Add(rngImage.Left, rngImage.Top, rngImage.Width, rngImage.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export folder & filename, "JPG"
    End With
    ws.ChartObjects(ws.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    
    ' return status
    CopyRangeToJPG = folder & filename
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, wow that looks pretty advanced ! I didn't quite understand:

"Set the initial image range and then offset it after each email sent ." How do I do that ? Because when I run the code it's the first range in all the emails, I'm missing the first part "Set rngImage = sh.Range("F27:J28")
Set rngImage = rngImage.Offset(rngImage.Rows.Count)"

Comment: Yours, but without this part Set the initial image range and then offset it after each email sent .

Set rngImage = sh.Range("F27:J28")
Set rngImage = rngImage.Offset(rngImage.Rows.Count)

Comment: @Asmaa Does the first email not have an image named `Image_27.jpg` and the second email have `Image_29.jpg`, etc ?

Comment: No it has the attachment in Column C and the first image in the bodymail

Comment: @Asmaa Does it not have an image as an attachment also ? Did you replace the function CopyRangeToJPG also

Comment: No, not in the email. Although, when I use Test = False, the first email comes out with the image in the mail body and a message "runtime error (big number)
Automation Error
The specified file can not be found". When I set it to True, a message (not email) pops up: "Image: C:\Users\...\Image_27.jpg and the body message"

Comment: @Asmaa Look like it is working in test, does the second email in test show "Image: C:\Users\...\Image_29.jpg. ? Run a few more in test and then look in C:\Users\...\ folder for different images. The "specified file can not be found" message might be an attachment, does column C:Z include the full path and filename ? Comment out the `.Attachments.Add filename` line and see if it works without attachments.

Comment: Oh my, it finally worked, THANK YOU. There's a small issue though, between each mail generation, I get the message "Could not attach ...@....com". Normally the emails are in column B and not C to Z, why the code tries to attach them ?

Comment: @asmaa OK found the error - see update to this line `Set rngA = cell.Offset(,1).Resize(, 24) ' C:Z attachments`